# why boost::call_traits<double>::param_type is "const double&", while not "double"

Tags: c++, boost, parameters

I'm using the code "boost::call_traits::param_type" on a win32 program@windows 7 machine. To my surprise, it's not "double" but "const double&".

I thought all primitive types are good to use "pass by value" for function parameters, isn't that a common sense? Because many people would use is_pod to determine using reference or not, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

That optimisation apparently only applies to "small" built-in types, according to the [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm).

From a quick look at the [source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/detail/call_traits.hpp), it looks like "small" types are considered as those that satisfy `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void *)`. On a 32 bit machine this obviously doesn't include `double`.

In some cases it may well be better to pass parameters as `double` rather than `double const&`, but as always, you'd have to benchmark and test...

Answer (score -1):

`boost::call_traits` class template has not been specialized for `double`. The primary class template returns `const T &`, that is why it is `const double &`, rather than `double`, although it doesn't matter much in this case, but it does matter if `T` is class type, which has huge data members. To avoid unnecessary copy, it is const reference.